# window.Open Open popup Instead of new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a, ajax function in jQuery and I want in complete function to open a url in a new window or tab.

```
<a href="#" onclick="Add('1','http://www.google.com');return false;">Link</a>
```

And :

```
function Add(ID, url)
{
    var data = "{'ID' : '" + ID + "'}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Function.ashx/Add",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function ()
        {
           window.open(url);
        }
    });
}
```

window.open function works as popup but I want to open the link in a new window. [w3School Example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_openwindow) works prefect.
But my browser detects it as a popup and blocks it.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to open a new window programmatically without triggering the popup blocker.

Comment: @Pekka : if you look at the w3 example it open as window not popup.

Comment: mmmm, I *think* that is because it's a manual click triggering it, which is not the case in your Ajax callback. But good question, interested to see what comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you specifically wait till the AJAX call completes to load the URL?

Why not simply trigger the AJAX call and open the new window directly after.

Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Add('1','http://www.google.com');return false;">Link</a>
```

```
function Add(ID, url)
{
    var data = "{'ID' : '" + ID + "'}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Function.ashx/Add",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: beacuse its trigger and my ajax doesn't call my Add function in Function.ashx. could you write a sample?

Comment: It's because in your code, the window.open() call is not initiated by a click. It's initiated by the AJAX callback. In my code, there is no AJAX callback, the window.open() call is made immediately after you make the AJAX call, directly within the Add() function, which was initiated by a user click, and thus the Browser allows it to open a window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing w3cschool.com probably gets the popup previlige for being an authorised tutoring site.

AFAIK, any means to open an extra window without direct user interaction (e.g. a click) is considered a "popup" and would be blocked by most of the browsers with popup blocker enabled. Your best bet is probably open the link upon a click and inject whatever you want upon the AJAX completion:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="Add('1')">Link</a>
```

---

```
function Add(ID, url)
{
    var newWindow = window.open(url);
    var data = "{'ID' : '" + ID + "'}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Function.ashx/Add",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (data)
        {
           // do whatever you want with newWindow
        }
    });
}
```