# JavaScript popup opening external page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am struggeling to implement a function to open a new window with an external link. I am creating dynamic content and would like to write a function that opens up a pop/up window with the given link. Please help. I like jquery dialog boxes, and lightwindo etc. But am unable to implement any of these, any help would be gerat, am stuck and frustrated with this supposingly small issue . . . No option has worked for em so far. here the code of how i display my results, and how i think I have to call the function to open a new window. So the second function here is the one I would need some help with, to open a nice pop-up window displaying the information..

```
// --------------------- display the course results -> structuring the returned array, to output all information into a table ----------------------
function displayCourses()
{

    var str = ' <table border="0" width="530">' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td width="150">Title / course code</td>' +
                    '<td>INFO</td>' +
                '</tr>';

    if(curCourseList == null)
    {
        str = str + '<tr><td colspan="2"><div id="msgDips"></div></td></tr>';
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < curCourseList.length; i++)
        {
            str = str + '<tr><td valign="top" width="150"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showCourse(\''+curCourseList[i][0]+'\')" >' + curCourseList[i][0] + ' <br /> </a>' + curCourseList[i][1] +'<br>'+ curCourseList[i][3] +'<br /><br />'+ curCourseList[i][4] +'</td><td>' + curCourseList[i][2] +'</td></tr>';
        }
    }

    str = str + '</table>';

    document.getElementById("courseContainer").innerHTML = str;
    if(curCourseList == null)
    {
        getLangToken('99');
    }

}    
function showCourse(code)
{
    //alert(1)
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'formPostsUser.php?reqtype=getCourse',
        data:'coursecode='+ code,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And seriously any help will be greatly ap[preciated. am in such deep shit atm

**EDIT---------------**

It is the window.open bit i would liek to replace to open a nice fancy pop-up, not new browser window or page

Comment: You don't need ajax or anything like that if you open it in a proper popup. Just put the url together correctly like `var url = 'http://example.com'` and call `var newwindow = window.open(url, name, params);` and that's done. No need for jQuery at all.

Comment: that newwindow bit, i would liek replace, with a script that opens a nice pop-up window, rather that new browser window or tab !!

Comment: Do you know about the `+=` operator? **And why in <insert something here>'s name do you use synchronous ajax requests?!**

Comment: dont know !!! I wish I would understand JS then I wouldnt be here asking questions !

Answer (score 1):

I do not know WHY you say a dialog does not work or specifically if jQuery UI dialog does not work for you, but just in case:

```
$(function() {
    $("<div id='helpDialog' style='display:none' />").appendTo(document);
    $("#helpDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $("#helpDialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
        "Close": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    })
});

function helpPopUp(page, height, width) {
    $("#helpDialog").dialog('option', 'height', height);
    $("#helpDialog").dialog('option', 'width', width);
    $('#helpDialog').load(page);
    $('#helpDialog').dialog("open");
}
helpPopUp('#helpDialog', 'Help/Summary.html', 550, 750);
```

You could of course, modify the `.load(page)` to be custom IF needed referencing the page in your url.

Here is a simple sample of the above with a slight mod to load your table instead of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/ABqrD/1/

Comment: i dont get it. I like the answer, and you can show me a dialogbox, but I dont get where I am supposed to implement this, and make my link work to open up a page !? The table is doen, my results r deiplayed ! I just need a pop-up, to open a new whole page to display other results related to the item the user clicked !!

Comment: at the script i posted, teh function showCourse i need modified to open a new specific page, with a string passed on of teh item they want to view !

Comment: like i dont even know if this is supposed to go into my JS file, or the actual php page !?!?!? and a div, is not good enough i believe, as I need to load a whole page, and run a whiole new query in the DB !?

Comment: Is there a live version that we can reference?

Answer (score 0):

If your triggering the window opening via anything other than user interaction it will most likely be blocked. Have you checked for notices pertaining to this?

Comment: no its is a link, created with the first function, once the user presses a link, it is supposed to call the function and open a new pop-up

Comment: From your code sample it's being called inside an AJAX callback. In most cases, anything other than direct/immediate interaction will be blocked.

Comment: See the following answer for better clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308286/window-open-open-popup-instead-of-new-window

Comment: and I'd like a pop-up window, not new browser page or tab !!

Comment: Why not use a jQuery plugin, shadowbox would be perfect; http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Comment: I have tried dialog box and lightbox. They all dont work ! Lightbox, for example, ends up opening a new browser tab in this instance. I had a simple working example, but when implementing it in this format, where the link is created through JS, it did not work !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a real popup, you could try to create a `<div>` which 'hovers' above the page with something like

```
.hoverwindow {
     position:absolute; 
     width: ...px; 
     height:...px; 
     margin:auto;
     z-index:10; /*ensure that it's displayed on top*/
}
```

You could do this with a small modification of your function:

```
function showCourse(code)
{

$.ajax({
    async:false,
    type: "POST",
    url: 'formPostsUser.php?reqtype=getCourse',
    data:'coursecode='+ code,
    success: function(data) 
    {
        var newwindow = $('<div class="hoverwindow" />');
        newwindow.html(data).appendTo('body');
    }
});
}
```

Although frankly this is pretty much what plugins for "popups" do so all of this should be readily available online if you search for it. Hence why I have not bothered to actually try and test this code - it is simply to give an idea of what you could do.

Comment: the problem here lies within the page structure i believe. I mentioned that including jquery plugins such as dialog box ot light box failed here ! they do not work, since my content is all created dynamically, so i need a fuinction within same JS file to open a nice pop-up window instead of browser tab or page ! and teh code did not work !

Comment: if it be available, I wouldnt write here ! Been trying this since couple of days ! I have working examples, with plugins that work on diff pages ! but not in this particular instance !

Comment: What has the content being created dynamically got to do with the snippet you have provided? The AJAX request references a server-side script which returns the contents of the lightbox, correct?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether content is added dynamically or from page load; whatever is on the page can be manipulated by JS. Sometimes there are issues because code is run when the corresponding elements are not loaded yet but this is not usually an issue with AJAX. What you need to do is find out why things don't work on your page if they do on others. There is always a reason. The console which comes with most browsers is one thing that can help you figure it out.

Comment: I am using firfox tools for this. When I, for example, implement lightbox, its JS prototype file makes other things not function !! The dialog box plugin, also doesnt work on this page ! But the current functions run very smooth and nice indeed !